# How to trigger IOException in response.body().string() with MockWebServer

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp, mockwebserver

I have this retrofit call:

```
api.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

        try {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) { // 200 - 300
                String responseBody = response.body().string();
                ...
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

and want trigger the `IOException` in `.string()` with MockWebServer.

I tried

```
        MockResponse mockResponse = new MockResponse()
            .setResponseCode(200)
            .setSocketPolicy(SocketPolicy.DISCONNECT_DURING_RESPONSE_BODY)
            .setBody("{}");
```

but that ends up in `OnFailure`.

How can I trigger the `IOException`?

Answer (score 3):

Something like the following

```
  private void responseBodyFail(Protocol expectedProtocol) throws IOException {
    // Use a 2 MiB body so the disconnect won't happen until the client has read some data.
    int responseBodySize = 2 * 1024 * 1024; // 2 MiB
    server.enqueue(new MockResponse()
        .setBody(new Buffer().write(new byte[responseBodySize]))
        .setSocketPolicy(SocketPolicy.DISCONNECT_DURING_RESPONSE_BODY));
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. It still ends up in "onFailure". I think the connection should be successful, but I need to tamper with the response body.

Comment: That's the API. So probably best to make a PR with a bug reproduction and file a bug.

Comment: What do you mean by "That's the API."? Are you saying this is an issue with retrofit?

Comment: Please make a reproducing test and submit a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit by default buffers the whole response into memory before passing it to you, meaning any `IOException` has been encountered (and passed to `onFailure`) before it has even constructed the `Response<T>` to give you.

You could make the test code work by adding the `@Streaming` annotation onto your interface method, however I suspect it's better to just leave it as-is and not attempt to test this case, since it evidently ought to not happen in practice.

You can see where they buffer it [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/1490e6b1f90c616e2283b098a2c8e51a88cc97c2/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/BuiltInConverters.java#L32-L36) and [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/1490e6b1f90c616e2283b098a2c8e51a88cc97c2/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/BuiltInConverters.java#L97-L110)